# SOLR and accented characters

Tags: solr, accent-insensitive

I have an index for occupations (identifier + occupation):

```
<field name="occ_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="occ_tx_name" type="text_es" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />


<!-- Spanish -->
<fieldType name="text_es" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This is a real query, for three identifiers (1, 195 and 129):

```
curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.11:8983/solr/cyp_occupations/select?indent=on&q=occ_id:1+occ_id:195+occ_id:129&wt=json"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"occ_id:1 occ_id:195 occ_id:129",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "occ_id":1,
        "occ_tx_name":"Abogado",
        "_version_":1565225103805906944},
      {
        "occ_id":129,
        "occ_tx_name":"Informático",
        "_version_":1565225103843655680},
      {
        "occ_id":195,
        "occ_tx_name":"Osteópata",
        "_version_":1565225103858335746}]
  }}
```

Two of them have accented characters, and one not. So let’s search by occ_tx_name without using accents:

```
curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.11:8983/solr/cyp_occupations/select?indent=on&q=occ_tx_name:abogado&wt=json"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"occ_tx_name:abogado",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "occ_id":1,
        "occ_tx_name":"Abogado",
        "_version_":1565225103805906944}]
  }}

curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.11:8983/solr/cyp_occupations/select?indent=on&q=occ_tx_name:informatico&wt=json"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"occ_tx_name:informatico",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound”:1,”start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "occ_id":129,
        "occ_tx_name":"Informático",
        "_version_":1565225103843655680}]
  }}


curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.11:8983/solr/cyp_occupations/select?indent=on&q=occ_tx_name:osteopata&wt=json"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"occ_tx_name:osteopata",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

I am very annoying about the fact that the last search ‘osteopata’ fails, while ‘informatico’ succeed. The source data for the index is a simple MySQL table:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`occ_occupation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`occ_occupation` (
  `occ_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `occ_tx_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`occ_id`)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The collation of the table is “utf8mb4_general_ci”. The index is created with DataImportHandler. This is the definition:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.11:3306/mydb"
        user=“mydb” password=“mydb” />
    <document name="occupations">
        <entity name="occupation" pk="occ_id"
            query="SELECT occ.occ_id, occ.occ_tx_name FROM occ_occupation occ WHERE occ.sta_bo_deleted = false">
            <field column="occ_id" name="occ_id" />
            <field column="occ_tx_name" name="occ_tx_name" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I need some clue to detect the problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using solr-6.3.0, and I'm starting the server with this command: solr start -a "-Duser.language=es -Duser.country=ES -Duser.timezone=Europe/Madrid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have discovered the source problem. I have opened my SQL load script with VI, in hex mode.

This is the hex content for 'Agrónomo' in an INSERT statement: 41 67 72 6f cc 81 6e 6f 6d 6f.

```
6f cc 81!!!! This is "o COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT" UTF code!!!!
```

So that's the problem... It must be "c3 b3"... I get the literals copy/pasting from a web page, so the source characters on the origin was the problem.

Thanks to both of you, because I have learning more about SOLR's soul.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` to your filter analyzer chain or even better create a new fieldType:

```xml
<!-- Spanish -->
<fieldType name="text_es_ascii_folding" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" format="snowball" />
    <filter class="solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

> This filter converts alphabetic, numeric, and symbolic Unicode
>   characters which are not in the Basic Latin Unicode block (the first
>   127 ASCII characters) to their ASCII equivalents, if one exists.

This should let you to match the search even if the accented character is missing.
The downside is that words like "cañon" and "canon" are now equivalent and both hit the same documents IIRC.

Comment: Hi. I have added the filter "solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory", but I get the exact same results...

Comment: You have to reindex the entire collection

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mysql or your jvm settings have anything to do with this. I suspect one works and the other does not probably due to the SpanishLightStemFilterFactory.

The right way to achieve matching no matter the diacritics is to use the following:

```
  <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
```

Put that before your tokenizer in both index and query analyzer chains, and any diacritic should be converted to the ascii version. That would make it work always.

Comment: go to Analysis tab an look at verbose output of that word in bot index and query side

Comment: It is insane! In Solr Admin, I have selected my index, and then clicked on Schema section. Then, I have selected the field 'occ_tx_name', and then, "Load term info" button, so I can see top 10 terms listed.  I have changed 10, to 278, to see all terms. Each term in the list is an HTML Anchor, that link to a SOLR query. And, I can't believe that I'm seeing...

Comment: In the list, all the terms have accented characters... All but "informatico"! I will give you an example. This is the anchor associated to the stored term "informatico" (lowercase without accented character): <a ng-href="#/cyp_occupations/query?q=%7B!term+f%3Docc_tx_name%7Dinformatico" class="ng-binding" href="#/cyp_occupations/query?q=%7B!term+f%3Docc_tx_name%7Dinformatico">informatico</a>.

Comment: And this is the anchor associated to "osteópata": <a ng-href="#/cyp_occupations/query?q=%7B!term+f%3Docc_tx_name%7Dosteo%CC%81pata" class="ng-binding" href="#/cyp_occupations/query?q=%7B!term+f%3Docc_tx_name%7Dosteo%CC%81pata">osteópata</a>... As you can see, "osteópata" has been stored with de accented character.... I don't know why, but this search succeed: curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.11:8983/solr/cyp_occupations/select?q=occ_tx_name:osteo%CC%81pata&indent=on&wt=json"

Comment: you have reindexed after changing the schema to add the charfilter right??

Comment: Yes, I have reindexed several times to make sure. Only the 'á' is transformed to 'a'. é í ó ú remains the same....